# Can't download windows installer wubi

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

I was trying to download the windows installer through the link provided on the page for the 12.04 version, but it is giving me to download the 707MB of ISO file which I already have.

Please can anyone help me on this one?

Thank you.

Comment: If you already have the iso, why not burning it?

Comment: Wubi is not really recommended now. I suggest you try burning the .iso file and do a proper installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&bits=&release=lts

If that does not work then try this one and scroll down to where you can click on
'Get The Installer':http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

If it still doesn't work you need to clear your browser's cache and cookies!